# Django Loading up Class based model data on a template

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django before this only made 1 project and that was just a follow along video so obviously the fix is probably very easy, but I am trying to make a restaurant reservation page, and later on there will be user authentication to only show the reservation that particular user made, but right now I want to display all of the reservations in my modal and trying to learn how to actually display the data.

here's the modal:
https://gyazo.com/066e3e060492990008d608a012f588f3

here's the view: https://gyazo.com/6947ed97d84b38f1e73680e28f3a0a9a

Here's the template: https://gyazo.com/966c4810b3c7f4dd8dad2e5b71c2179c

I am spent about 3 hours watching other videos on people loading there modal data in there website and when they do it I understand everything but for some reason I can't apply that to my own project, my guess is my for loop is wrong since I have a hard time with writing them and seem to always mess up, so any help so I can at least start looking in the right direction would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `class based views` you'll have to work with `django` conventions. For example where you have `reservations = Reservation.objects.all()`, `reservations` is not a defined class attribute for the `class based view`. What you can do is rename it to `queryset` instead.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ReservationList(ListView):
     model = Reservation
     queryset = Reservation.objects.all()
     context_object_name = 'reservations'  # using this attribute to alias the queryset
     template_name = "make_a_reservation.html"
```

This way you can now use the name `reservations` in your `template` as you did with:

```
{% for i in reservations %}
     ...
{% endfor %}
```

That should work.

Comment: thank you that works, I had it set to quaryset before, but nothing worked pretty much just needed the "context_object_name = 'reservations' " to make it work, I googled about it and apparently if I don't have the the context_name would be set to "model_name of the model that the queryset is composed from, with postfix '_list' appended." but I tried removing the "context_object_name = 'reservations'" and then using the model_name with _list appended and it was still not loading, could you try and explain why, from what I understand if I made the loop "for i in Resersation_list" it should work

Comment: If you should remove `context_object_name = reservations` then the `django` will pass a variable called `object_list` to the template. You can iterate over the `object_list` like `for i in object_list`. But I'd suggest using the `context_object_name = reservations`. And for the record, `for i in Reservation_list` would not work. :-)

Comment: ya I already tried and was confused why it was not working, but I assume its better to use "context_object_name = reservations" incase I have multiple models so django knows which one I want to iterate, anyways thanks for the help, django seems so much more simple when watching the follow along videos, doing a project yourself is much harder

Comment: Yes, Django in itself is a heavy framework but becomes fun if you get familiar with it. I still have a lot to learn myself :-D. My pleasure helping bro.